# How do I resolve an OBDC connection failure in old C++ app?

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio, odbc

We have an old C++ server app (written with Visual Studio 6) that continually connects and disconnects to a Sql Server database.

This app runs continually as a service, and most of the time everything runs fines, but every few days the connection process will return one of the errors below.  Further attempts to connect don't work (the app will retry a connection up to 3 times) until it is terminated and restarted.

The errors are as follows:

1. Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 8
2. SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_DBC failed

We have tried setting the IRPStackSize to 30, but that has not resolved the problem.

Any other ideas?

To Neil Butterworth:  The app closes every connection it opens, so the issue is not connections that are left open.  How would I free handles?

Comment: Probably run out of handles - are you freeing them anywhere?

Comment: `NET HELPMSG 8` returns "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command." The memory leak might not necessarily be related to ODBC data access.